# Operator valued polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

I was reading [Reed & Simon](https://www.amazon.com.br/Functional-Analysis-Methods-Mathematical-Physics-ebook/dp/B00BCRMN4G), where the following theorem is stated and proved.

> **Theorem:** Let $A_{k}$ be a self-adjoint operator on (a Hilbert space) $\mathscr{H}_{k}$. Let $P(x_{1},...,x_{N})$ be a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $n_{k}$ in the $k$-th variable and suppose that $D_{k}^{e}$ is a domain of essential self-adjointness for $A_{k}^{n_{k}}$. Then:

(a) $P(A_{1},...,A_{N})$ is essentially self-adjoint on $D^{e}=\otimes_{k=1}^{N}D_{k}^{e}$.

(b) The spectrum of $\overline{P(A_{1},...,A_{N})}$ is the closure of the range of $P$ on the product of the spectra of the $A_{k}$. That is:
$$\sigma(\overline{P(x_{1},...,x_{N})})=\overline{P(\sigma(A_{1}),...,\sigma(A_{N})}$$

**Question:** What does it mean the operator valued polynomial $P(A_{1},...,A_{N})$? Are the products of variables $x_{k}$ understood as tensor products when the polynomial is considered in terms of operators? In other words, if $P(x_{1},x_{2}) = x_{1}^{2}+2x_{1}x_{2}$, does it mean that $P(A_{1},A_{2}) = A_{1}^{2}\otimes I + 2A_{1}\otimes A_{2}$?